# Как найти в строке коды символов вроде \x07 используя re Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, ascii

Имеется строка с закодированными управляющими символами ascii вроде "Информационное письмо \x07 Текст \x07 Ещё текст." Надо из неё выловить \x07 и заменить на ' '. Следующий паттерн не отлавливает, хотя в онлайн проверяльщике показывает, что должен.

```
pattern = [\\]x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}
```

Использую Пайчарм и  Пайтон 3.8. Подскажите, плиз, как отлавливать такие штуки.

Comment: Управляющие символы ASCII не имеют никакого отношения к escape-последовательностям в строковых литералах

Comment: Если вам надо удалить символ с кодом 7, значит так и делайте `s = s.replace('\x07', '')`

Comment: Можно ещё по коду символа через `ord` ловить, но в целом нужно знать точный список отлавливаемых символов, тогда можно выбрать оптимальное решение, вариантов много как ловить можно.

Comment: @CrazyElf, как я понимаю точный список символов лежит [тут](https://istarik.ru/blog/programmirovanie/53.html) в первой таблице(только там они в  виде 0x07 представлены) и хотелось бы отлавливать их все. Можно их тупо захардкодить, благо их  не так много, но хотелось бы более изящного решения.

Comment: @Maeglin вы точно уверены, что вам нужно отлавливать табуляцию и перенос строки?

Comment: @andreymal, не уверен. Изначально проблема была в  том, что openpyxl не позволил записать похожий текст в табличку.  [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49844925/openpyxl-utils-exceptions-illegalcharactererror) я прочитал, что дело в escape-последовательностях. И  решил их все отлавливать, чтобы подстраховаться. Но у  меня  не вышло. И  вот я здесь)))

Answer (score 4):

Если нужно найти символы с кодами меньше 0x20, можно просто указать в регулярном выражении эти символы в виде кодов `\xNN` как диапазон:

```
import re

text = "Информационное письмо \x02 Текст \x07 Ещё текст."
pattern = r"[\x00-\x19]"

print(re.findall(pattern, text))
print(re.sub(pattern, '', text))
```

Вывод:

```
['\x02', '\x07']
Информационное письмо  Текст  Ещё текст.
```

Но правда будет реагировать и на `'\n'`, например (код 0x0a), и другие управляющие символы, типа таба `'\t'`, возврата каретки `'\r'` и т.д. - у них у всех код меньше 0x20.

Comment: Судя по ссылке, которую дал автор вопроса, ему нужны выкосить всё, что меньше 0x20 )  По крайней мере в первой итерации решения

Comment: @CrazyElf а, тогда я угадал с решением)

Comment: @insolor, спасибо за идею. Оказалось, что она очень хороша!

Answer (score 1):

Судя по комментарию автора, нужно просто фильтровать все `ASCII` символы, код которых меньше, чем код "пробела" (32). Можно это сделать так:

```
s = "Информационное письмо \x07 Текст \x07 Ещё текст. \x02 \x1f И прочее \x0d и прочее"
print(''.join(ch for ch in s if ord(ch) >= 32))
```

Или через `filter` тоже самое:

```
print(''.join(filter(lambda x: ord(x) >= 32, s)))
```

Вывод:

```
Информационное письмо  Текст  Ещё текст.   И прочее  и прочее
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вроде подходит для моих целей. 
Но как сделать тоже самое регуляркой всё ещё интересно.

Answer (score 1):

Решение проблемы с помощью регулярок заключается в функции repr().

```
old = repr("Информационное письмо \x07 Текст \x07 Ещё текст.")
pattern = r'\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}'
new = re.sub(pattern, '', old)
print(old)
print(new)
```

Вывод:

```
'Информационное письмо \x07 Текст \x07 Ещё текст.'
'Информационное письмо  Текст  Ещё текст.'
```

Comment: На реальном кейсе у этого метода обнаружился серьезный косяк. Все '\t', '\r','\n' и прочая фигня прописываются в своём символьном представлении. 
В таблице появились записи вроде "\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nFrom: info@example.ru", что не очень удобно.